# How do I access an asset's URL when linked via reference in Sanity Studio?

Tags: sanity

I want to upload PDFs in Sanity Studio, then link to those PDFs in the main site content.

I've added a reference to a document which has a 'file' field in it to my simpleBlockContent input in Sanity Studio.

I've created a document schema for the PDF:

```js
export default {
  title: "PDF Upload",
  name: "pdfDocument",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "title",
      type: "string",
      title: "Title",
      description: "This title will be used as a caption for the download.",
    },
    {
      name: "pdfFile",
      type: "file",
      title: "PDF File",
      options: {
        accept: ".pdf",
      },
      validation: (Rule) => Rule.required(),
      description: "Note that the file name will be visible to end users downloading the file.",
    },
  ],
};
```

And I'm attempting to reference it in my input component's schema:

```js
export default {
  title: "Simple Block Content",
  name: "simpleBlockContent",
  type: "array",
  of: [
    {
      title: "Block",
      type: "block",
      styles: [],
      marks: {
        annotations: [
          {
            name: "pdfLink",
            type: "object",
            title: "PDF download link",
            fields: [
              {
                name: "pdfReference",
                type: "reference",
                title: "PDF Document",
                to: [{ type: "pdfDocument" }],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

However when I add pdfLink to my serializers.js in the frontend, nothing resembling a link to the file is present in the data passed to it from my _rawContent graphql query that handles all other page content.

How can I access the information needed to build a URL that links to the uploaded asset?

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to do this in a serializer, but it looks as though the asset URL should be accessible in the returned document, according to the [docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/assets#example-of-returned-asset-document-2cee91f4f62d):

> ### Example of returned asset document:

```
{
  "_id": "image-abc123_0G0Pkg3JLakKCLrF1podAdE9-538x538-jpg",
  "_type": "sanity.imageAsset", // type is prefixed by sanity schema
  "assetId": "0G0Pkg3JLakKCLrF1podAdE9",
  "path": "images/myproject/mydataset/abc123_0G0Pkg3JLakKCLrF1podAdE9-538x538.jpg",
  "url": "https://cdn.sanity.io/images/myproject/mydataset/abc123_0G0Pkg3JLakKCLrF1podAdE9-538x538.jpg",
  "originalFilename": "bicycle.jpg",
  "size": 2097152, // File size, in bytes
  "metadata": {
    "dimensions": {
      "height": 538,
      "width": 538,
      "aspectRatio": 1.0
    },
    "location":{ // only present if the original image contained location metadata
      "lat": 59.9241370,
      "lon": 10.7583846,
      "alt": 21.0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to get instant link in sanity studio when someone upload file in sanity and couldn't find any good solution so I came up with my own

#### Problem

let people upload files to sanity and get instant link that they can copy and paste in blog, case study etc

#### Solution

use slug as in option you have acces to doc where you can generate link my code

```js
import { tryGetFile } from '@sanity/asset-utils'; // this function creates production link

const pdfUploader = {
  name: 'pdfUploader',
  title: 'Upload PDF and Get Link',
  type: 'document',
  preview: {
    select: {
      title: 'title',
    },
  },
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'title',
      title: 'Title',
      description: 'Name displayed on pdf list',
      type: 'string',
      validation: (Rule) => [Rule.required()],
    },
    {
      name: 'pdfFile',
      title: 'Upload PDF File',
      description: 'PDF File you want to upload, once you upload click generate URL',
      type: 'file',
      validation: (Rule) => [Rule.required()],
    },
    {
      name: 'generatedPDFURL',
      title: 'Generate URL Link to this pdf',
      description:
        'Click GENERATE to get Link to pdf file, if you by mistake change it, click generate again. Then Copy link below and paste it anywhere you want',
      type: 'slug',
      options: {
        // this source takes all data that is currently in this document and pass it as argument
        // then tryGetFile() - getting file from sanity with all atributes like url, original name etc
        source: ({ pdfFile }) => {
          if (!pdfFile) return 'Missing PDF File';

          const { asset } = tryGetFile(pdfFile?.asset?._ref, {
            // put your own envs
            dataset: process.env.SANITY_DATASET,
            projectId: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
          });
          return asset?.url;
        },
        // this slugify prevent from changing "/" to "-" it keeps the original link and prevent from slugifying
        slugify: (link) => link,
      },
      validation: (Rule) => [Rule.required()],
    },
  ],
};

export default pdfUploader;
```

After this in sanity upload file and then click **GENERATE** to get link
Hope it helps people who are looking for similar solution, slug is not perfect choice but it's working :)